# RHEL/CentOS 7 NIC Boot Order

Tags: networking, centos, ssh

Is there a way to ensure that one NIC boots and obtains it's IP address before another?

I'm currently using 2/4 NICs on my server, one enp3s0f1 is a public network/IP and the other enp4s0f1 is bonded to an internal network. When I do a hard reboot, enp4s0f1 always comes up first. This means that all services like sshd, httpd, etc all bind to the internal network, and remote connections no longer function.

[This](https://serverfault.com/questions/614216/how-do-i-control-the-ordering-of-network-interfaces) seems like a similar issue but not the same since my devices are getting consistently named based on [Scheme 3](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/ch-consistent_network_device_naming).

Should I just bind each each service like sshd, httpd to a specific NIC or IP Address?

enp3s0f1 Config:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp3s0f1
UUID=bea91dea-5c34-4012-b185-743d223f1247
DEVICE=enp3s0f1
ONBOOT=yes
ZONE=public
IPADDR=76.81.xxx.xxx
PREFIX=29
GATEWAY=76.81.xxx.xxx
DNS1=209.18.47.61
```

enp4s0f1 Config (note that while DHCP, the address is reserved in the DHCP Route Table such that it is static):

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=none
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp4s0f1
UUID=ec51c215-e32b-4924-a90b-661fd2431168
DEVICE=enp4s0f1
ONBOOT=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding services like sshd, httpd and etc, doesn't rely on NIC boot order. By default they listen on all addresses(on 0.0.0.0). I don't see your network configuration, but I can assume, that you have issue with default route on internal network NIC. So you shold check your network configuration to resolve issue.

Comment: Can you tell me what config I should be looking at? I just added the two for each interface but I don't think the issues is there. From what you stated, then my issue is that the internal network boots first, and the public one just never obtains an IP. Why would that be?